# Downloading PDF for IE9 using anychart

Tags: anychart

I am trying to save my chart as PDF using anychart, It works fine above IE9 but not for  IE9. Does Anychart support IE9 for PDF export.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AnyChart support IE9 (tested 9.0.8112.16421) for PDF export, please, try the following sample in IE9. Export to PDF is available from context menu ('save as PDF') and as API method (click label on top-left).

[image: IE9 tested version]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
            var stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");

            var chart = anychart.line([
                {x: "January", value: 49},
                {x: "February", value: 45},
                {x: "March", value: 9},
                {x: "April", value: 4},
                {x: "May", value: 17}
            ]);
            chart.left("5%");
            chart.title("Save chart as PDF file");
            chart.container(stage);
            chart.draw();

            var customLabel = anychart.standalones.label();
            customLabel.background({fill: "#9E9E9E"});
            customLabel.text("Save image");
            customLabel.fontColor("#fff");
            customLabel.padding(5);
            customLabel.offsetX(5);
            customLabel.listen("click", function () {
                // Saves into PDF file.
                chart.saveAsPdf("a4", true, 100, 50, "PdfChart");

            });
            customLabel.listen("mouseOver", function () {
                document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
            });
            customLabel.listen("mouseOut", function () {
                document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
            });
            customLabel.container(stage);
            customLabel.draw();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried using chart.saveAsPdf("a4", true, 100, 50, "PdfChart") but it lands me to error, saying object expected and stage is undefined . And the above example doesn't save pdf  in any IE versions I just checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test of the example above in IE9, the export to PDF works well. Please, try the same build as in the test - 9.0.8112.16421

[image: PDF export IE9]

Comment: we have checked with the anychart team, they told as they aren't supporting IE9  as of now for export PDF.